# Double pointer pointing to random address of same heap realm

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, double-pointer

I have a static char array in func1(). And when Im calling func2() I am passing it the address of the char array(double pointer) because I am allocating memory inside of it. Then, doing some calculations with the pointer and on the second call of function the pointer doesn't get reseted, but it's pointing somewhere in range of my allocated bytes.

Let's say I allocated 500 Bytes. First call begins from 0, and second just continues.

Let's take now another approach as example, allocating memory in func1() and not needing the double pointer with the same code, whenever calling func2() the pointer gets reseted and begins from 0.

Why am I experiencing this?

CASE 2

```
func2(char *array){   

 ++array; // position 1
}

func1(){
    static char *array;

    if(array == NULL){
    array = (char*) malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    }

    func2(array);
    func2(array); // again position 1


}
```

CASE 1

```
func2(char **array){
    if(*array == NULL){
    *array = (char*) malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    }

    ++*array; // position 1
}

func1(){
    static char *array;

    func2(&array);
    func2(&array); // calling it again, pointer goes on position 2
    // or it starts counting for ex. from position 55(random said)

}
```

Comment: please paste the code

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Yeah I did, should be enough to understand the concept. Sorry for not beeing able to produce much

Comment: In case 2 (the first one shown), func2 does nothing.  It's just incrementing its argument, which is strictly local to func2 and has no visibility in func1.  In case 1 (the second one shown), I would expect array to be incremented in func1 after the call to func2 (after first being set in func2).  But your claims of randomness cannot be substantiated because you have not included any kind of test driver to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: ...and also `++array; // position 1` does not increment position 1 of the array but the pointer itself.

Comment: `*array == (char*) malloc(500 * sizeof(char));` should be `*array = malloc(500);` please take notice of compiler warning about the `==` error, and note too that `sizeof(char)` only clutters the code, it is `1` by definition.

Comment: Oh, good point, I had missed that.  Yeah, don't use comparison operators in place of assignment operators (or vice versa)!

Comment: That comparison operator is just a typomistake, I wrote that on-the-fly. Tom I actually had a question, in case 2 you said it's incrementing it's argument which is strictly local to func2, but isn't that argument from func1 beeing passed to func2? And by that mean, incremented?

Comment: @So in order to get the same behaviour in CASE 1 as in CASE 2 I would need to make a return pointer function(for the array), and a local scope pointer?

Comment: Imagine having inside one more command (**array)+5:CASE 1 and *array+5:CASE 2. Case 1 would always increment the last value where the pointer stopped, but in Case 2 it would always begin at the 0 element

Comment: @Maxitj can you please improve the question you are asking in the question itself? It's not clear which comments refers to which example, and what you are ultimately trying to achieve. If you could produce the MCVE for seems to be a fairly simple piece of code that demonstrates the fault, as requested, that would be a help. If you provide code with typos or that won't compile, some commenters can lose interest fast.

Comment: Yeah I totally get you, well my question stays simple. I'm waiting for the confirmation from Tom on part of the answer, and the other part is how could I make the Case 1 behave as Case 2?

Comment: Do you mean you are waiting for a reply from "@So"? Whoever that is.

Comment: From Tom actually but on that exact question :D I was using that @ as edit(as we usually use on forums), because I was too late to edit it regularly, not for refereeing to a person soz >.>

Comment: @TomKarzes I hope this gets to you :)

Comment: In case 2, func2 passes the variable "array" to func1.  This creates a local copy of array in func1.  If func1 changes that copy, func2 will never see the change.

Comment: @TomKarzes yeah thanks, I've got that, but the only way for the case 1 to behave same is to always save the start position so I can decrement the pointer?

Comment: @TomKarzes look what happened to me, I passed the array like in case 2 it got coppied and I changed some values, on the other call the values were present but the pointer started always from beginning? Could you please explain me this, I'd gladly choose your answer as solution!

Comment: Well, I'd like to help, but honestly I really have no idea what you're trying to do at this point.  You know why case 1 and case 2 behave differently.  I don't know what your latest code looks like, and I don't really understand what your goal is.

Comment: @TomKarzes yeah BUT, not gladly saying somebody, who looks more experienced than I do, to have no right, but in Case 2 if the function 1 changes changes that copy it will be visible in func2! Try yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

> I passed the array like in case 2 it got coppied and I changed some
>   values, on the other call the values were present but the pointer
>   started always from beginning? Could you please explain me this…

In the case of calling `func2(array)`, not a copy of the allocated array object is passed, but only a copy of the pointer value `array`, of course pointing to the very same memory address; thus, when `func2()` changed some values of the array object's elements, those changed values are naturally present on another call with the same object address, while when `func2()` changed its local copy of `array` by means of `++array`, this has no impact on `func1()`'s local pointer named `array`.

> … but the only way for the case 1 to behave same is to always save the
>   start position so I can decrement the pointer?

If you want the array object to be allocated in `func2(char **)`, as in case 1, but the `array` pointer not otherwise to be changed by `func2()`, you could write:

```
void func2(char **arrayaddress)
{
    if (*arrayaddress == NULL) *arrayaddress = malloc(500);
    char *array = *arrayaddress;    // make own local copy, keep *arrayaddress unchanged
    ++array;    // position 1
}

void func1()
{
    static char *array;
    func2(&array);
    func2(&array);  // calling it again, pointer unchanged
}
```